# Angularjs addClass/ removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm quite new to Angularjs I've been trying to get this code working, but I've not been able. 
I need to add and remove a class on click.

I have the jQuery version working fine :

```
   $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
      $('.container').stop().addClass('active');
});

   $('.close').on('click', function() {
      $('.container').stop().removeClass('active');
 });
```

In my HTML:

```
   <div class="toggle" toggle-class="active"></div>
```

From what I've read, using a directive would be most suited.
In my directive I have this code:

```
 app.directive('toggleClass', function() {
      return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'LoginC',
link: function(scope,  element) {
       element.click(function(){
            if(element.attr('toggle') === 'active') {
                angular.element(element).addClass('active');
            } else {
                 angular.element(element).removeClass('active');

            }
        });
    }
};
```

});

I am missing something. Please could someone advise? I would really appreciate it. 
Thank you

Comment: 'toggle' is not an attribute in you HTML. It is a value of attribute class. So "element.attr('toggle')" is always undefined in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Your directive can be simplified greatly.

```
angular.module("myApp").directive('toggleClass', function() {
     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         controller: 'LoginCtrl',
         controllerAs: 'LoginC',
         link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
             elem.on('click', function(e){
                 if (attrs.toggleClass === 'active') {
                     elem.toggleClass('active');
                 };
             });
         }
     }
})
```

Comment: Thank you @georgeawg. I've ended up using an ng-class and it works fine. Not sure what's best, but its a simpler solution for now. ;)

Answer (score -1):

As Sado noted, it is even easier

```
<div ng-class="{'active':someVal}" ng-click="someVal = !someVal"></div>
```

Comment: You can also add the angular ng-click directive to it like <div ng-class="{'active' : someVal}" ng-click="someVal = !someVal"></div>

Comment: Sorry, brain freeze - this is indeed the best way to do it

Comment: oops, i said also not the best genius!

Comment: Thanks all. I'll give it a go.

Comment: Ok so I've done this: Is it right? I can see it changing, but I think my directive is still wrong. Sorry guys :(

Comment: <div class="toggle "ng-class="{'active':toggle}" ng-click="toggle =      !toggle"></div>

Comment: can't change scope within dom events without notifying angular to run a digest

Comment: @charlietfl is correct. -1 for 1st part of answer which is incorrect(need digest cycle to updated scope variable)..

Comment: @pankaj, I s trying to leave a bit of op's original code in answer. Have corrected

Comment: Hmm kind of, but still trying to get it to work. I'm new to Angularjs so still have lots to learn. Thanks for asking :)

Comment: @1313 let me know of you need help, or mark the question answered

Comment: Unfortunately, Yes I still need help :(

Comment: Have you removed ask the jquery code now? What is still not working precisely

Comment: Yes I have. the directive isn't working. It's not doing anything. I don't think it's doing what the jquery code is doing.

Comment: You don't need the directive anymore for the class handling

Comment: Oh ok...is it all done in the controller? How would I had the active class to the container?

Comment: The fragment of code left in my answer is all you need. At least of all toy want is to toggke the active class with each click

Comment: Do you mean this?: <div ng-class="{'active':someVal}" ng-click="someVal = !someVal"></div>  But then if I have <div class="toggle"></div> and want to to set the active class on the container every time this div is clicked, how would I write that?

Comment: I think you should post more of your HTML. Your current approach is not the so-called 'angular way' and the way to do it will be much simple, but I'm no longer sure what your actual objective is

Comment: Don't worry @SimonH. I will try to sort it out. I think I'm just confusing you now. My code is at the top. Thanks for your help.